# Poscondition for ArrayList add method

Tags: java, arraylist, push, addition, contract

How would you guys write a postcondition for this method?

```
public void push(ArrayList n) {
    numbers.add(n);
}
```

I tried:

```
@Ensures("result == true && this.equals(old(new ArrayList((numbers.add(n)))))")


(result == true) => because add() returns always true
(this.equals(old(new ArrayList((numbers.add(n)))) => because this is equal to the old this with a deep constructor of the old this, adding n
```

My problem is that the postcondition gives me this error
"java: error in contract: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to NaturalList
  null"

Seems like the deep copy constructor returns true. How would you guys do it?

Comment: getting close to lisp huh? :D

Comment: Hahaha I know, this is the the way we write the contracts using deep copy constructors xD